# Counting number of repetions in a particular column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count

for eg:
a dataframe "housing" has a column "street" with different street names as levels.
I want to return a df with counts of the number of houses in each street (level), basically number of repetitions.
what functions do i use in r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
library(dplyr)

housing %>% group_by(street) %>% summarise(Count=n())
```

Comment: This saved me thanks! in addition, how do i ignore na values in housing while applying these arguments?

Comment: @bverc You could add a new pipe like `filter(!is.na(yourvariable))`. Let me know if I can help more!

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

`summary` gives the first 100 frequencies of the factor levels. If there are more, try:

```
table(housing$street)
```

For example, let's generate one hundred one-letter street names and summarise them with `table`.

```
set.seed(1234)
housing <- data.frame(street = sample(letters, size = 100, replace = TRUE))
x <- table(housing$street)
x
# a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
# 1 3 5 6 4 6 2 6 5 3 1 3 1 2 5 5 4 1 5 5 3 7 4 5 3 5
```

As per OP's comment. To further use the result in analyses, it needs to be included in a variable. Here, the `x`. The class of the variable is `table`, and it works in base R with most functions as a named vector. For example, to find the most frequent street name, use `which.max`.

```
which.max(x)
#  v 
# 22
```

The result says that the 22nd position in `x` has the maximum value and it is called `v`.

Comment: Thanks, that was so simple. is this in base r?

Comment: Also, I'm not able to perform any analysis using this method. for eg: to find the highest value

Comment: Simply send the table result into a variable and use it as a vector. I added an example to the response.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple ways, for instance with base R using `table()`:

```
table(housing$street)
```

It can also be done through dplyr, as illustrated by Duck.

Another option (my preference) is using data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(housing)
housing[, .N, by = street]
```